# If Bitlocker is turned on, How to decrypt OS volume when boot up?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker, efs

I want to know decrypting process when boot up encrypted volume using BitLocker.

Because MS says, it is encrypting entire disk drive whether the volume is installed OS or not, which means the file system will be encrypted.

I found some documents about EFS that decrypting each file before load.
However, I couldn't find how it does work when boot OS volume encrypted with BitLocker.

That's all I do until now.

Anyway I want to know how does it work.

Comment: EFS and Bitlocker are entirely separate things.  You do understand that right?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I know it is different things. I just compared EFS and BitLocker to find differences for understanding after finding this.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/whats-the-difference-between-bitlocker-drive-encryption-and-encrypting-file-system

Answer (score 1):

When using Bitlocker for full-disk encryption you require a ["System Reserved" partition](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/) that is separate form your encrypted boot/OS partition.

This System partition is not (and cannot be) encrypted, as it contains boot and Bitlocker startup files used during boot to unlock Bitlocker, so the the OS can be loaded from the encrypted drive.

From MS' [BitLocker Drive Encryption Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732774.aspx):

> The hard disk must be partitioned with at least two drives:
>
> - The operating system drive (or boot drive) contains the operating system and its support files; it must be formatted with the NTFS file
>     system.
> - The system drive contains the files that are needed to load Windows after the BIOS has prepared the system hardware. BitLocker is not
>     enabled on this drive. For BitLocker to work, the system drive must
>     not be encrypted, must differ from the operating system drive, and
>     must be formatted with the NTFS file system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007. 
I know MSR has data of BitLocker and it is loaded when boot up. 
MS says, BitLocker is not only encrypting files but also free-space of disk drive. so If does, i want to know the way how OS find and load specific file like DLLs, Docs, or EXEs when user request to open something. 
That is my point that i wonder. 
I'm not sure you understand exactly I said because I am not fluent english.

Comment: @Ki-HoonKang “how OS find and load specific file like DLLs, Docs, or EXEs” – Like before. BitLocker is essentially a wrapper around raw disks. It encrypts/decrypts on the fly. Inside, it’s still NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the post being old, but:

Bitlocker decrypts data when sectors or clusters are read from the drive, and encrypts it as they're being written. It encrypts the whole filesystem.

Encrypting free space is an option when encrypting a drive for the first time, so even deleted files' data becomes encrypted.